# Converting Random Pairing Function from VBA to GAS

Tags: vba, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working to create a random pairing algorithm for my bass club.  The idea is to pair a value in Column A (Boaters) with a value in Column B (non-boaters).  If there are no more non-boaters, any remaining boaters should be paired unless only one unpaired boater remains.

I found some VBA code online, which works fine in Excel, but all of my club's stuff is in Google Sheets and I'd like to have the same pairing function in GAS.

I've tried my best to convert the VBA code to GAS, but honestly, I have some experience with VBA and I'm still a relative novice at GAS, although I'm learning.

I've pasted the two VBA functions below, followed by the GAS conversion I've been working on.  The comments show the areas where I'm having trouble, particularly with the called sorting function (vSortM), although I'd welcome a second set of eyes to make sure I haven't incorrectly coded something else.

Can anyone advise if I am performing the conversion from VBA to GAS correctly?

**Pairing Algorithm in VBA that I found online:**

```
Option Explicit 

Sub test() 
    Dim Boters(), NonBoters(), i As Long, x As Long 
    Boters = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value 
    Redim Preserve Boters(1 To UBound(Boters), 1 To 2) 
    NonBoters = Range("b1", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value 
    Redim Preserve NonBoters(1 To UBound(NonBoters), 1 To 2) 
    Randomize 
    For i = 1 To UBound(Boters) 
        Boters(i, 2) = Rnd 
    Next 
    For i = 1 To UBound(NonBoters) 
        NonBoters(i, 2) = Rnd 
    Next 
    VSortM Boters, 1, UBound(Boters), 2 
    VSortM NonBoters, 1, UBound(NonBoters), 2 
    x = Application.Min(UBound(Boters), UBound(NonBoters)) 
    With Cells(1, 4).Resize(x, 2) 
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents 
        .Columns(1).Value = Boters 
        .Columns(2).Value = NonBoters 
    End With 
    If x < UBound(Boters) Then 
        For i = x + 1 To UBound(Boters) Step 2 
            If i + 1 > UBound(Boters) Then Exit For 
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Boters(i, 1) 
            Cells(i, 5).Value = Boters(i + 1, 1) 
        Next 
    End If 

End Sub 


Private Sub VSortM(ary, LB, UB, ref) 
    Dim M As Variant, i As Long, ii As Long, iii As Long, temp 
    i = UB: ii = LB 
    M = ary(Int((LB + UB) / 2), ref) 
    Do While ii <= i 
        Do While ary(ii, ref) < M 
            ii = ii + 1 
        Loop 
        Do While ary(i, ref) > M 
            i = i - 1 
        Loop 
        If ii <= i Then 
            For iii = LBound(ary, 2) To UBound(ary, 2) 
                temp = ary(ii, iii) 
                ary(ii, iii) = ary(i, iii): ary(i, iii) = temp 
            Next 
            ii = ii + 1: i = i - 1 
        End If 
    Loop 
    If LB < i Then VSortM ary, LB, i, ref 
    If ii < UB Then VSortM ary, ii, UB, ref 
End Sub
```

**My attempt at converting the Pairing Algorithm in GAS**

```
    function test() {
  //Get values for Column A and Column B starting at Row 5
    var ssMatch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pairings');
    var bRange = ssMatch.getRange("A5:A").getValues();
    var nBRange = ssMatch.getRange("B5:B").getValues();
  //Determine length with data to exclude blansk
    var bLast = bRange.filter(String).length;
    var nBLast = nBRange.filter(String).length;
  //Get values for boaters & nBoaters without blanks
    var boaters = ssMatch.getRange(5,1,bLast).getValues();
    var nBoaters = ssMatch.getRange(5,2,nBLast).getValues();
//  Populate boaters & nBoaters arrays using random numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < bLast; i++) { 
        boaters[i][1] = Math.random();
      Logger.log(boaters);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j<nBLast; j++) {
        nBoaters[j][1] = Math.random();
          Logger.log(nBoaters);
        }
    vSortM (boaters, 1, bLast, 1);
    vSortM (nBoaters, 1, nBLast, 1);
  //Determine whether there are more boaters or non-boaters
    var x = Min(bLast, nBLast);
  //Write boater & nBoater values in Columns 
  //NEED SOME HELP HERE:  Certain this isn't correct for GAS
    Cells(1,4).Resize(x, 2);
        Cells.CurrentRegion.ClearContents;
        Cells.Columns(1).setValues(boaters);
        Cells.Columns(2).setValues(nBoaters);
  //If no more nBoaters, pair remaining unpaired boaters
  if (x < bLast) {
      for (var i = x + 1; i<bLast; i = i + 2) {
        if (i + 1 > bLast) { break;}
        else {
          //THINK I DID THIS RIGHT, BUT NOT SURE
            ssMatch.getRange(i,4).setValue(boaters[i][0]);
            ssMatch.getRange(i,5).setValue(boaters[i+1][0]); 
        }  
      }
    }
  }

//Having some trouble converting this from VBA to GAS
// not sure how to deal with the ary parameter and m statement
 function vSortM(ary, lB, uB, ref) {
    var temp = 0;
    var i = uB;
    var ii = lB; 
    var m = [parseInt((lB + uB) / 2), ref];
    while (ii <= i);{ 
    while ([ii, ref] < m); { 
            ii++; 
            while ([i, ref] > m); {
            i--; 
            }
            if (ii <= i); { 
            for (var iii = 0; i<=(ary, 2);) {
                temp = [ii, iii];
                [ii, iii] = [i, iii];
                [i, iii] = temp;
                }
            ii++;
            i--;
            }
        }
        if (lB < i) {
        vSortM(ary, lB, i, ref);
        }
        if (ii < uB) {
        vSortM(ary, ii, uB, ref);
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: So you are **really** just asking someone to translate the working [vba] code into [google-app-script] for you...?

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm asking.  I've gotten as far as I can trying to convert it on my own.  As I said, I'm a novice with GAS and javascript, but I'm trying to learn.  I just need some help with the parts I can't figure out.  I've looked in the GAS reference, and tried to map the VBA over to GAS, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do some of the statements.

Comment: You might get a bit more traction with your question if you edit your question down to the specific issue like `if I query and update a Range like this in Excel - would I do it like this in GAS ... code...`. You have two quite long code blocks but they are a bit much to work through to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I have to agree with the others in the comments. The question is too broad. In https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask it says that questions should be reasonably scoped.

From what I see in your code that you ask for help.

```
 //NEED SOME HELP HERE:  Certain this isn't correct for GAS
   Cells(1,4).Resize(x, 2);
     Cells.CurrentRegion.ClearContents;
     Cells.Columns(1).setValues(boaters);
     Cells.Columns(2).setValues(nBoaters);
```

This section is easy to figure out by using the very well written documentation for GAS (always refer to it first before going anywhere else). In GAS you are essentially working with classes (or objects if you will). Here you will want the [sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to resize the row and column (2 seperate functions) and then a [range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) (which is retrieved from the sheet class) to clear and set values.

```
 //THINK I DID THIS RIGHT, BUT NOT SURE
   ssMatch.getRange(i,4).setValue(boaters[i][0]);
   ssMatch.getRange(i,5).setValue(boaters[i+1][0]);
```

Depends on what you want to accomplish. The syntax here is correct, you set a value for a single cell. Keep in mind that in google sheets it's best to try and batch such calls. So instead of setting a value on a cell by cell basis, you would get a range from A1 to B20 and set all values at once with a 2D array.

Finally you need to clarify what it is the second functions has to do and what it doesn't do right. Perhaps share a minimal example sheet (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)?